# Grouping by a field

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have a report where I need to group the items by PaymentMethod and then display a total below each group. I am right-clicking on the detail row and selecting `Add group > Adjacent Below` and then choosing the group by of PaymentMethod.

You can see that the top picture has a line that shows grouping the total row with the detail row, which is what I want. The picture at the bottom is what I am currently getting.

[image: This is how the grouping should look]

[image: This is the way it actually is grouping when I attempt it]

Comment: The child option is grayed out... anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong Add Group option.  You should select Add Group -> Child Group.

Comment: The Child group is grayed out

Comment: How about Parent Group?  You may have to play with the layout afterwards.